# C# десериализация JSON, необходимо вытащить запись из записи

Tags: c#, json, deserialize

Дан, к примеру, следующий JSON

```
{
  "main" {
    "temp": 33.5
  }
}
```

Необходимо записать значение в поле

```
internal class WeatherInfo
{
    [JsonPropertyName("main.temp")]
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

Но он не записывает его, видать атрибут задан неверно.
Как правильно его записать?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что `JsonPropertyName` позволяет задавать такой "шаблон"? На сколько я знаю, он лишь позволяет задать другое имя свойству, если то отличается от JSON (к примеру, в JSON у вас `object_id`, а вы хотите свойство в классе просто, `Id`). Так что, вам надо создать всю структуру классов, начиная от верхнего и заканчивая нижнего, где будет уже ваше свойство `temp`, ну, или писать конверторы.

Comment: Понятно, думал проблему можно решить добавлением атрибута.
А так да, тогда придется копировать структуру документа.
Спасибо!

Comment: @hlooo можно использовать `JsonPropertyName`, только оно вложенность не поддерживает. Т.е. Temperature должно быть с атрибутом `[JsonPropertyName("temp")]`, а сама WeatherInfo должно быть свойством ещё одного объекта, типа `internal class MainInfo { [JsonPropertyName("main")] public WeatherInfo Info { get; set; } }`. После этого можно делать десериализацию: `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MainInfo>(text);`. Плюс мне кажется, что у вас Json не валидный - после "main" должно быть двоеточие.

Comment: @John Согласен, после main пропустил двоеточие, но это я сам составлял его для простоты примера и ошибся. А так да, распарсил JSON именно таким образом, каким вы описали, спасибо!